# How do I get a bare FB login page?

Tags: authentication, facebook-php-sdk

OK, I understand the process of logging in to Facebook from my desktop app and I have an app working.   My question is more one of how do I get a login page that is simply a place to enter the email and password without all of the other extraneous stuff, join FB; pick a language; forgot my password; etc...

Comment: Get off the PHP SDK and use the Graph API. Your life will begin to shine.